# Limit of 100 items returned in ajax call-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to increase the size of response that gets returned by this call from the default 100 to something bigger.
Here's is how my ajax call looks like:

```
var request2 = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://appscan87:9443/ase/api/issues?query=Application%20Name%3DMigros%202&columns=status,cvss,issuetype,location,severity&sortBy=-id&dojo.preventCache=1453360377756",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; application/javascript"
        });
```

I have read in other posts, about adding the limit:1000 in the call parameters, but that is not working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It all depends on the API you're pulling from, which you don't specify. If the documentation for that API says to add a `limit` parameter then you might need to add `&limit=1000` to the end of the URL.

Comment: in other words, read the documentation for said api. The limit is set by the api, so unless the api gives you an option to change it, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Mike and Kevin.
The API is REST, and I discovered it has a limit of 100, so can't change it
The documentation advises you need to filter the results to get less than 100 results

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; application/javascript"` — The content type header can only take one content type … and is nonsense on a GET require anyway since there is no request body to describe the content type of.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Quentin removed the tag altogether

Answer (score 2):

After consulting the api documentation, its a limit that can't be changed.
Thanks Kevin and Mike

Comment: why don't you use 'post' instead of 'get' ?

Comment: POST would be if I want to push the data somewhere. 
What I want is to pull data (hence GET).
Thanks @DinoMyte